# Unable to mock error in fastAPI dependency

Tags: pytest, fastapi, python-unittest

Im writing tests for my status check endpoint. Here is the endpoint.

```
@router.get("/", response_model=HealthStatus, summary="Database Health Check")
async def db_health_check(_: None = Depends(check_project_db_status_dependency)):
    return HealthStatus(status="Running")
```

Here is the dependency:

```
async def check_project_db_status_dependency(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_project_async_session)) -> None:
    try:
        result = await session.execute(text("SELECT 1"))
        if result.scalar() != 1:
            raise DatabaseNotAccessible(ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.DB_NOT_RESPONDING_CORRECTLY)
    except OperationalError as exc:
        raise DatabaseNotAccessible(ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DB) from exc
```

For the custom error I have a error route:

```
async def database_not_accessible_error_handler(request: Request, exc: DatabaseNotAccessible) -> JSONResponse:
    """
    Handler for DatabaseNotAccessible exception.

    Args:
        request (Request): Request object.
        exc (DatabaseNotAccessible): Exception object.

    Returns:
        JSONResponse: Response object.
    """
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        content={"detail": str(exc)},
    )
```

Im trying to write tests where I can actually mock both of the error scenarios. However, when I tried using `patch.object` and also `mocker.patch.object` from `pytest` with the dependency, but got 200. Also tried just `patch`, `mocker.patch` with path to the dependency but still got 200.

Tried overwriting the dependency and even though it works, it does not really test the actual dependency and also its flagged in coverage.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("project_name", PROJECTS)
def test_project_health_check_db_unreachable(
    async_main_session: IAsyncSession,
    project_name: str,
):
    def raise_error():
        raise DatabaseNotAccessible(ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.DB_NOT_RESPONDING_CORRECTLY)

    app.dependency_overrides[check_project_db_status_dependency] = raise_error
    response = client.get(build_health_check_url(project_name))
    assert response.status_code == 500
    assert response.json()["detail"] == ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.DB_NOT_RESPONDING_CORRECTLY.value


@pytest.mark.parametrize("project_name", PROJECTS)
def test_project_health_check_fail_to_connect(
    async_main_session: IAsyncSession,
    project_name: str,
):
    def raise_error():
        raise DatabaseNotAccessible(ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DB)

    app.dependency_overrides[check_project_db_status_dependency] = raise_error
    response = client.get(build_health_check_url(project_name))
    assert response.status_code == 500
    assert response.json()["detail"] == ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DB.value
```

The structure of my project is:

```
main.py
app/
├── main.py
├── dependencies.py
└── routes/
    └── api_v1/
        └── status.py
```

Comment: If you want to test the logic inside `check_project_db_status_dependency` instead of only inside the health check point, override `get_project_async_session` instead and return an object that implements `execute` but returns something other than 1 - and one version that raises the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MatsLindh for the suggestion. Indeed I was supposed to mock the `get_project_async_session` instead of `check_project_db_status_dependency` Here is the solution:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("project_name", PROJECTS)
def test_project_health_check_db_unreachable(
    async_main_session: IAsyncSession,
    project_name: str,
):

    class MockResult:

        def scalar(self) -> int:
            return 2

    class MockSession:

        async def execute(self, *args, **kwargs) -> MockResult:
            return MockResult()

    app.dependency_overrides[get_project_async_session] = MockSession
    response = client.get(build_health_check_url(project_name))

    assert (
        response.status_code == 500
    ), f"Expected 500 Internal Server Error status code but got {response.status_code}."
    assert response.json()["detail"] == ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.DB_NOT_RESPONDING_CORRECTLY.value, (
        f"Expected response: {ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.DB_NOT_RESPONDING_CORRECTLY.value} "
        f"but got {response.json()}."
    )


@pytest.mark.parametrize("project_name", PROJECTS)
def test_project_health_check_fail_to_connect(
    async_main_session: IAsyncSession,
    project_name: str,
):

    class MockSession:

        def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
            raise OperationalError("DB is not reachable", None, BaseException("DB is not reachable"))

    app.dependency_overrides[get_project_async_session] = MockSession
    response = client.get(build_health_check_url(project_name))

    assert (
        response.status_code == 500
    ), f"Expected 500 Internal Server Error status code but got {response.status_code}."
    assert response.json()["detail"] == ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DB.value, (
        f"Expected response: {ErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR.value.FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DB.value} "
        f"but got {response.json()}."
    )
```